# For loop not incrementing only when qInfo looks for array value

Tags: c++, qt, for-loop

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

int ages[4] = {23,7,75,1000};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qInfo() << ages;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        qInfo() << i;

    }

    a.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

returns:

0x7ff7d01f3010                                                                                                          0                                                                                                                       1                                                                                                                       2                                                                                                                       3                                                                                                                       4

To the terminal

But

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

int ages[4] = {23,7,75,1000};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qInfo() << ages;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        qInfo() << i;
        qInfo() << ages[i];
    }

    a.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

returns:

4713                                                                                                                    0                                                                                                                       4714                                                                                                                    0                                                                                                                       4715                                                                                                                    0                                                                                                                       4716                                                                                                                    0                                                                                                                       4717                                                                                                                    0                                                                                                                       4718

etc. to the terminal.

As a beginner this behavior is not intuitive and I do not understand what the difference is.

The first code was my attempt to see if my for loop was written incorrectly, but it acts as expected.

Comment: `int ages[4] = {23,7,75,1000};` -- `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` -- `qInfo() << ages[i];` -- Buffer overrun on the last iteration of the loop.  Thus the behavior is undefined.

Comment: you're invoking UB by accessing `ages` out of bound. Its last index is 3, not 4

Comment: Ah, thanks. Makes sense. I tested with cout and got the same behavior so I figured I did something wrong. I knew the array started at 0 and still tried to get four. Thanks. Could someone post an answer so I can accept the question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour in your code because you are indexing the array out of its size. Your array has four elements, but you seem to try to access 5 elements in its. So, the last iteration is undefined behaviour.

You could write this instead:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

int ages[4] = {23,7,75,1000};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qInfo() << ages;
    for (int age : ages)
        qInfo() << age;

    a.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

Depending on your compiler, you could use the sanitizer options to catch these, for example:

```
-fsanitize=undefined
```

I personally use these in my projects:

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "(Clang|GNU)")                                
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Werror)                         
  add_compile_options(-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer)
  add_link_options(-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer)
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")                                   
  set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "/w")                  
endif()                                                                         
                                                                                
add_compile_definitions(QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0xFFFFFF)
```

I would also like to point out that you should use `size_t` instead of `int` for the loop counter as a good practice.

It is also worth pointing out that you should avoid using raw arrays in a C++, and especially Qt program. There are better choices, like:

```
std::array
std::vector
QList
```

etc.

Furthermore, you could even merge these two lines:

```
a.exec();
return 0;
```

Into the following (this is how it is typically written):

```
return a.exec();
```

Comment: Thanks for the good practice tips, I will include size_t in my loops from now on. The return 0 is an artifact from me following a course and showing they're the same, but I do appreciate the added advice.